# Une bonne traduction pour « vanish », en parlant des mathématiques

Tags: anglais, terminologie, mathématiques

Une fonction est dite « s’annuler » quelque part sur son ensemble de définition lorsqu’elle y atteint 0, ou plus généralement, quand elle atteint le premier élément neutre d’un anneau. Pour désigner la même chose, on utilise « cancel out », et « vanish » en anglais.
Les mots « cancel out » me semblent une bonne traduction pour le mot français ci-dessus, tandis que « vanish » veut plutôt dire « disparaître ».

Je me suis servi du Wiktionnaire pour traduire ce mot. Quant à « disparaître », le Wiktionnaire me donnait cinq explications, mais aucune n’était liée aux fonctions. Quant à « vanish », celui-ci m’apprenait que le mot se traduit par « diminuer jusqu'à zéro ».

L’emploi de cette tournure me semble maladroit :

- J’ai besoin d’une expression plus courte, car il y a des circonstances où elle doit être utilisée plusieurs fois de suite.
- Ce mot laisse penser que la valeur de la fonction peut décroitre encore plus. C’est un sous-entendu que je veux éviter, car *f* s’annule en *x* seulement si *f(x)* vaut zéro.

C’est surtout la deuxième raison qui me dissuade de l’utiliser.

**Ma question**

- La tournure « se diminuer jusqu’à zéro », est-elle vraiment floue ?
- Quelle traduction de « vanish » dans ce cadre me conseillez-vous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Vanish" a deux sens, d'où sans doute le malentendu avec "diminuer vers zéro".

Un premier sens est synonyme de "cancel out" (f vanishes at x, f vanishes on A...), et je ne vois pas tellement d'autre traduction que "s'annuler" ou "être nulle" (en tout cas ce sont les formulations que j'utiliserais).

Le deuxième sens s'emploie quand une quantité s'approche arbitrairement près de zéro quand on prend une limite. Dans ce cas, on traduirait "f(x) vanishes as x goes to a" par "f(x) tend vers zéro quand x tend vers a". On comprend assez bien "diminuer vers zéro" dans ce contexte, mais la formulation est incorrecte, puisqu'elle implique non seulement que f(x) s'approche de zéro, mais aussi qu'elle le fait en décroissant (ce que "vanish" n'indique pas il me semble).

Answer (score 4):

Comme @JalB l'a dit on dit qu'une fonction **s'annule en x** lorsque f(x) vaut 0, exemple :

> f(x) = 3x^2-4 **s'annule** quand x vaut -4

Ensuite si la fonction se rapproche sans jamais atteindre 0 on dit que la fonction **tend vers 0**, 0 est donc le **minorant** ou le **majorant** de la fonction. Exemple

> f(x) = 1/4x  est **minorée** et **tend vers** 0 lorsque x tend vers +infini

Une fonction ne peut **s'annuler** qu'en 0 mais peut cependant **tendre** vers n'importe quelle valeur (que ce soit un nombre réel, ou même l'infini).

Comment: Plusieurs inexactitudes ici. 1) La fonction f(x)=3x^2-4 ne s'annule pas en -4 (f(-4)=3*16-4). 2) Qu'une fonction tende vers 0 n'implique pas que 0 soit un minorant ou un majorant (considérer x.sin((1/x) en zéro par exemple). 3) On dit qu'une fonction s'annule en 0 si f(0)=0 ; une fonction peut a priori s'annuler en tout point x (en revanche, dans ce cas f(x) vaut nécessairement zéro).

Answer (score 2):

On ne dit pas  « se diminuer jusqu’à zéro » on dit "***tendre vers 0***". Càd que sa valeur va en diminuant jusqu'à l'approche infinitésimale de 0 (égale ou pas).

Comment: Ceci ne me contente pas vraiment. J’ai voulu que la traduction puisse tenir lieu du mot « annuler ». J’avais égard à une explication de Wiktionary, voyez le lien suivant :
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vanish
Je n’ai pas tenu compte que ce mot puisse aussi vouloir dire quelque chose d’autre. Pensez-vous que je dois remanier ma question ?

Comment: D'après le Wiktionary je trouve que le choix de  **"la fonction s'annule à x/la valeur x"**  est plus correct. Le cas utilisé pour démontrer le terme ( f(x)=x^2) est particulier car il faut que X=0 pour annuler la fonction. Le terme "tendre vers" est plus général dans ce cas.